# Interfaces for mocking ConfirmEmailAsync and other UserManager methods in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to unit test this controller method, which comes out of the box in current MVC projects.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
    return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
}
```

The AccountController has a constructor which will take an ApplicationUserManager and a ApplicationSignInManager as parameters, and the matching properties with private setters to use for testing. However, I can't figure out how to mock out the ConfirmEmailAsync method.

You can mock various interfaces in the Identity namespace:

```
var store = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();

store.As<IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>>()
            .Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync("username1"))
            .ReturnsAsync((ApplicationUser)null);

var mockManager = new ApplicationUserManager(store.Object);

AccountController ac = new AccountController(mockManager, null, GetMockRepository().Object, GetMockLogger().Object);
```

But I can't find or figure out which Interface I need in order to create a mock of ConfirmEmailAsync.

How do I go about this? And for reference, is there a good way of finding out which interfaces these methods are on in order to mock and test them?

Comment: i got around this by abstracting most of the functionality of identity into its own project so that I can unit test it easier and reuse the abstraction in other projects. I started with this article http://timschreiber.com/2015/01/14/persistence-ignorant-asp-net-identity-with-patterns-part-1/ and then fine tuned it to suit my needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConfirmEmailAsync` is not currently part of an interface in the framework. It's in the `UserManager<TUser, TKey>` class which is the base class of Identity framework.

My solution?

**Abstract all the things**

I got around this by abstracting most of the functionality of identity into its own project so that I can unit test it easier and reuse the abstraction in other projects. I got the idea after reading this article

**[Persistence-Ignorant ASP.NET Identity with Patterns](http://timschreiber.com/2015/01/14/persistence-ignorant-asp-net-identity-with-patterns-part-1/)**

I then fine tuned the idea to suit my needs. I basically just swapped everything i needed from asp.net.identity for my custom interfaces which more or less mirrored the functionality provided by the framework but with the advantage of easier mockability.

IIdentityUser

```
/// <summary>
///  Minimal interface for a user with an id of type <seealso cref="System.String"/>
/// </summary>
public interface IIdentityUser : IIdentityUser<string> { }
/// <summary>
///  Minimal interface for a user
/// </summary>
public interface IIdentityUser<TKey>
    where TKey : System.IEquatable<TKey> {

    TKey Id { get; set; }
    string UserName { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
    bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    string EmailConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    string ResetPasswordToken { get; set; }
    string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

IIdentityManager

```
/// <summary>
/// Exposes user related api which will automatically save changes to the UserStore
/// </summary>
public interface IIdentityManager : IIdentityManager<IIdentityUser> { }
/// <summary>
/// Exposes user related api which will automatically save changes to the UserStore
/// </summary>
public interface IIdentityManager<TUser> : IIdentityManager<TUser, string>
    where TUser : class, IIdentityUser<string> { }
/// <summary>
/// Exposes user related api which will automatically save changes to the UserStore
/// </summary>
public interface IIdentityManager<TUser, TKey> : IDisposable
    where TUser : class, IIdentityUser<TKey>
    where TKey : System.IEquatable<TKey> {

    Task<IIdentityResult> AddPasswordAsync(TKey userid, string password);
    Task<IIdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(TKey userid, string currentPassword, string newPassword);
    Task<IIdentityResult> ConfirmEmailAsync(TKey userId, string token);
    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

IIdentityResult

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the minimal result of an identity operation
/// </summary>
public interface IIdentityResult : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> {
    bool Succeeded { get; }
}
```

In my default implementation of the identity manager i simply wrapped the `ApplicationManager` and then mapped results and functionality between my types and the asp.net.identity types.

```
public class DefaultUserManager : IIdentityManager {
    private ApplicationUserManager innerManager;

    public DefaultUserManager() {
        this.innerManager = ApplicationUserManager.Instance;
    }
    //..other code removed for brevity
    public async Task<IIdentityResult> ConfirmEmailAsync(string userId, string token) {
        var result = await innerManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, token);
        return result.AsIIdentityResult();
    }
    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at Typemock.

Actually you don't need any interface if you are using [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com), you just need to fake the IdentityResult you require and change the behavior of the asynchronous method "ConfirmEmailAsync", for example a test that checks the scenario of an Unconfirmed email:

```
[TestMethod, Isolated]
public async Task TestWhenEmailIsBad_ErrorMessageIsShown()
{

    // Arrange
    // Create the wanted controller for testing and fake IdentityResult
    var controller = new aspdotNetExample.Controllers.AccountController();
    var fakeIdentityRes = Isolate.Fake.Instance<IdentityResult>();

    // Fake HttpContext to return a fake ApplicationSignInManager
    var fakeSIM = Isolate.WhenCalled(() => controller.UserManager).ReturnRecursiveFake();

    // Modifying the behavior of ConfirmEmailAsync to return fakeIdentityRes
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeSIM.ConfirmEmailAsync("", "")).WillReturn(Task.FromResult<IdentityResult>(fakeIdentityRes));
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeIdentityRes.Succeeded).WillReturn(false);

    // Act
    var result = await controller.ConfirmEmail("", "") as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Error", result.ViewName);
}
```