# How to use DI with UserManager and UserStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, inversion-of-control

Given a typical setup of a MVC controller constructor passing `UserManager` (which takes `UserStore`) to it's parent class, how would this be converted to be injected via IoC?

Starting with this:

```
public AccountController()
    : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
        new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
{
}
```

I would think something like this:

```
public AccountController(IUserStore store)
    : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store)))
{
}
```

Though this does, of course, lose the `IdentityDbContext`.

How should the IoC be setup and how should the constructor be defined to allow injection of the UserManager, UserStore and IdentityDbContext?

Comment: This will help: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/

Comment: Hey, that's excellent - thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to create some classes to allow for easier injection.

Let us start with the UserStore. Create the desired interface and have it inherit from `IUserStore<ApplicationUser>`

```
public IUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser> { }
```

Create an implementation as follows.

```
public ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserSTore {
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        :base(dbContext) { }
}
```

The UserManager can then be done as desired in the OP.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser> {

    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserSTore userStore) : base(userStore) { }

}
```

SO now all that is left is to make sure that which ever IoC container you decide to use registers the necessary classes.

```
ApplicationDbContext --> ApplicationDbContext 
IUserStore --> ApplicationUserStore
```

If you want to go a step further and abstract the UserManager then just create an interface that exposes the functionality you want

```
public interface IUserManager<TUser, TKey> : IDisposable
    where TUser : class, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<TKey>
    where TKey : System.IEquatable<TKey> {
    //...include all the properties and methods to be exposed
    IQueryable<TUser> Users { get; }
    Task<TUser> FindByEmailAsync(string email);
    Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(TKey userId);
    //...other code removed for brevity
}

public IUserManager<TUser> : IUserManager<TUser, string>
    where TUser : class, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<string> { }

public IApplicationUserManager : IUserManager<ApplicationUser> { }
```

and have you manager inherit from that.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationUserManager {

    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserSTore userStore) : base(userStore) { }

}
```

This now means that the Controller can now depend on an abstraction and not on implementation concerns

```
private readonly IApplicationUserManager userManager;

public AccountController(IApplicationUserManager userManager) {
    this.userManager = userManager;
}
```

And again you register the interface with the implementation in the IoC container.

```
IApplicationUserManager  --> ApplicationUserManager
```

UPDATE:

If you are feeling adventurous and want to abstract identity framework itself take a look at the [answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38464229/5233410)

Comment: How do you then access the `DbContext` from `ApplicationUserManager `?