# Asp.net Core Identity unit test controller actions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, asp.net-core-identity

I'm having a problem working out how and what to test.

I have a controller that injects `UserManager` and calls the `CreateAsync` method to create a new user.

I don't want to test the Identity user manager as this has clearly been thoroughly tested already. What I would like to do is test that the controller runs through the correct paths (in my case, there are 3 paths, sending responses back with either model state errors, identity response errors or a simple string)

Should I be trying to create a mock of the user manager in order to create my test (I'm not sure how to set up user manager as a mock dependency)
Second, how can I set conditions to verify that the controller has taken a given path.

I am using *xUnit* and *Moq*.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MembershipController : BaseApiController
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public MembershipController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpGet("RegisterNewUser")]
    public HttpResponseMessage RegisterNewUser([FromBody] NewUserRegistration user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser newUser = new ApplicationUser();
            newUser.UserName = user.username;
            newUser.Email = user.password;
            IdentityResult result = _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, user.password).Result;

            if (result.Errors.Count() > 0)
            {
                var errors = new IdentityResultErrorResponse().returnResponseErrors(result.Errors);
                return this.WebApiResponse(errors, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var errors = new ViewModelResultErrorResponse().returnResponseErrors(ModelState);
            return this.WebApiResponse(errors, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        return this.WebApiResponse(
                    "We have sent a valifation email to you, please click on the verify email account link.",
                    HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

In My unit test I have the following to test a happy path scenario

```
    [Fact]
    public void RegisterNewUser_ReturnsHttpStatusOK_WhenValidModelPosted()
    {
        var mockStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        var mockUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(mockStore.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        ApplicationUser testUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "user@test.com" };

        mockStore.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(testUser, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
           .Returns(Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success));

        mockStore.Setup(x => x.FindByNameAsync(testUser.UserName, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                    .Returns(Task.FromResult(testUser));


        mockUserManager.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(testUser).Result).Returns(new IdentityResult());

        MembershipController sut = new MembershipController(mockUserManager.Object);
        var input = new NewUserInputBuilder().Build();
        sut.RegisterNewUser(input);

    }
```

Where "input" in sut.RegisterNewUser(input); refers to a helper class which constructs the viewmodel which the controller action requires:

```
public class NewUserInputBuilder
{
    private string username { get; set; }
    private string password { get; set; }
    private string passwordConfirmation { get; set; }
    private string firstname { get; set; }
    private string lastname { get; set; }

    internal NewUserInputBuilder()
    {
        this.username = "user@test.com";
        this.password = "password";
        this.passwordConfirmation = "password";
        this.firstname = "user";
        this.lastname = "name";
    }

    internal NewUserInputBuilder WithNoUsername()
    {
        this.username = "";
        return this;
    }

    internal NewUserInputBuilder WithMisMatchedPasswordConfirmation()
    {
        this.passwordConfirmation = "MismatchedPassword";
        return this;
    }

    internal NewUserRegistration Build()
    {
        return new NewUserRegistration
        { username = this.username, password = this.password,
            passwordConfirmation = this.passwordConfirmation,
            firstname = this.firstname, lastname = this.lastname
        };
    }
}
```

My aim here is to force 3 conditions via tests:

1. Create a valid viewmodel and return a success message
2. Create a valid viewmodel but returns a IdentityResponse error (eg. user exists) which gets converted to
3. Create an invalid viewmodel and returns Modelstate errors

The errors are handled using a abstract class which returns a json object
The base class for the controller simply constructs a `HttpResponseMessage` for return.

Basically I want to check that the correct error response class is called by forcing the test down the modelstate error path, the identityresult.errors path and that the happy path can be achieved.

Then my plan is to test the error response classes in isolation.

Hopefully that is enough detail.

Comment: Though it would require some refactoring, take a look at the answer I gave here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883635/how-to-use-di-with-usermanager-and-userstore/41885293#41885293 . A few quick tips when it comes to mocking. Do not mock what you do not own. Classes should depend on abstractions and not concretion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still not really sure on how to test my code though. I was looking for a slightly more complete answer.

Comment: Well then I suggest you first start by trying something. If you get stuck show what you tried and then we can see where we can help. Based on what you have provided so far it would be too broad for a *complete* answer. The community will try to help as best it can but do not expect that it will just do everything for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have updated the post to include my test code, some associated classes and the specifics of what I need to test.

Comment: Good. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Initial assessment of happy path shows me that there is no need to *setup* the UserStore as you will be overriding the user manager directly. Mehod under test should be made async and not use blocking calls ie `.Result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mehod under test should be made async and not use blocking calls ie `.Result`

```
[HttpGet("RegisterNewUser")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RegisterNewUser([FromBody] NewUserRegistration user) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var newUser = new ApplicationUser() {
            UserName = user.username,
            Email = user.password
        };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, user.password);
        if (result.Errors.Count() > 0) {
            var errors = new IdentityResultErrorResponse().returnResponseErrors(result.Errors);
            return this.WebApiResponse(errors, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    } else {
        var errors = new ViewModelResultErrorResponse().returnResponseErrors(ModelState);
        return this.WebApiResponse(errors, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    return this.WebApiResponse(
                "We have sent a valifation email to you, please click on the verify email account link.",
                HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Review of Happy path scenario and method under test shows that there is no need to *setup* the `UserStore` as test will be overriding the user manager virtual members directly.

Note the test has also been made async as well.

> 1. Create a valid viewmodel and return a success message

```
[Fact]
public async Task RegisterNewUser_ReturnsHttpStatusOK_WhenValidModelPosted() {
    //Arrange
    var mockStore = Mock.Of<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
    var mockUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(mockStore, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    mockUserManager
        .Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);

    var sut = new MembershipController(mockUserManager.Object);
    var input = new NewUserInputBuilder().Build();

    //Act
    var actual = await sut.RegisterNewUser(input);

    //Assert
    actual
        .Should().NotBeNull()
        .And.Match<HttpResponseMessage>(_ => _.IsSuccessStatusCode == true);        
}
```

> 2. Create a valid viewmodel but returns a IdentityResponse error (eg. user exists) which gets converted

For this you just need to setup the mock to return a result with errors.

```
[Fact]
public async Task RegisterNewUser_ReturnsHttpStatusBadRequest_WhenViewModelPosted() {
    //Arrange

    //...code removed for brevity

    mockUserManager
        .Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError { Description = "test"}));

    //...code removed for brevity

    //Assert
    actual
        .Should().NotBeNull()
        .And.Match<HttpResponseMessage>(_ => _.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

And for

> 3. Create an invalid viewmodel and returns Modelstate errors

You just need to set the model state of the controller so that it is invalid.

```
[Fact]
public async Task RegisterNewUser_ReturnsHttpStatusBadRequest_WhenInvalidModelState() {
    //Arrange
    var mockStore = Mock.Of<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
    var mockUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(mockStore, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    var sut = new MembershipController(mockUserManager.Object);
    sut.ModelState.AddModelError("", "invalid data");
    var input = new NewUserInputBuilder().Build();

    //Act
    var actual = await sut.RegisterNewUser(input);

    //Assert
    actual
        .Should().NotBeNull()
        .And.Match<HttpResponseMessage>(_ => _.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);    
}
```

*FluentAssertions* were used to do all the assertions. You could just as easily used `Assert.*` API.

This should be enough to get you on your way with the above question.

Comment: I'm almost lost for words. Thank you for the most amazing reply, this has really filled in the blanks and has really improved my understanding.

Comment: @BenWhite with unit testing you want to isolate the thing being tested. In cases where there are dependencies you want to be able to mock the dependencies so that tests can be exercised to have completed as intended. When you walk through the flow of your method under test, it will show you what needs to be manipulated to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way using NUnit (you could do something similar with xUnit), if you don't want to test the user manager. (I've also shown how the DbContext can be passed to the same controller, using an in-memory database that can be used for setting up mock data)

```
    private DbContextOptions<MyContextName> options;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContextName>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyDatabase")
            .Options;

        // Insert seed data into the in-memory mock database using one instance of the context
        using (var context = new MyContextName(options))
        {
            var testWibble = new Wibble { MyProperty = 1, MyOtherProperty = 2 ... };
            context.wibbles.Add(testWibble);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }


    [Test]
    public void Some_TestMethod()
    {
        // Use a clean instance of the context to run the test
        using (var context = new MyDbContext(options))
        {
            var store = new UserStore<MyUserType>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<MyUserType>(store, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            MyController MyController = new MyController(userManager, context);

            ... test the controller
        }
    }
```